# Website on iPad off screen

Tags: ipad, drupal-7

I am creating a fixed width website in Drupal and I'm having trouble getting the website to fill the viewport on the iPad ( have not tested smaller devices yet).

If you look at [cc-photobooths.mckernanms.com](http://cc-photobooths.mckernanms.com) in portrait view you will see that the form runs off the screen. It should'nt.

Then if you rotate to landscape view it still is off screen. Then back to portrait and it stays zoomed in instead of going backmtomthe original view.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Since you've included no details here at all and expect people to just view the site (on the "right" device) when it's fixed this question automatically loses its value.

Answer (score 2):

iOS devices use the Viewport metatag for setting resolutions specfic to its devices. You can set this and should help solve your issues.

Example Metatag for a 590px wide Viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=590">
```

I believe this link is a good place for reference on that. If you have any questions please ask.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html